# How can I pass my desired parameters to langchain tools module?

Tags: langchain

"Some of the tools in the tools module require parameters to be passed to use them, but the default parameters passed are not what the function needs. For example, if I pass in {"name": "name", "dt": 2020, "id": 123}, but only name is passed to the action_input of the tool function."

I want to pass the entire contents of my input to the function, so that I can parse it myself.
maybe use args schema?

Comment: Do you want to find out how multiple parameters can be passed to a tool (i.e. API function?)

Comment: yes！Do you known?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to place the function inside a class, where the parameters are passed when calling the class, and the function directly accesses these parameters

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,args):
        self.args = args
    def b(query):
        return self.args
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment to the original question ("Do you want to find out how multiple parameters can be passed to a tool (i.e. API function?)"), following may be solution:

```
def set_x_y(string):
    x_val, y_val = string.split(",")
    x_val = int(x_val.strip())
    y_val = int(y_val.strip())
    self.x = x_val
    self.y = y_val


tools = [
    Tool(
        name="SetXY",
        func=set_x_y,
        description="Sets the value for X and Y. The input to this tool should be a comma separated list of "\
                    "strings of length two. The first one is the value of X and the second one is the value of Y. "\
                    "For example, `3,4` would be the input if you want to set value of X to 3 and value of Y to 4"
    ),
]
```

Comment: thx you answer. I have also read the documentation, but in my use case, a string is not the parameter I want. Therefore, I placed the function inside a class, passed the parameters to the class first, and then called the function. I solved it using this method.